# SABR: how to deal with the wings?

Tags: options, volatility, sabr

I have experimented a bit with the SABR model. In particular I have calibrated it on EURUSD. Obviously, as SABR is a 3 parameter model, it will not fit the 5 market quotes consisting of ATM, 25 delta butterfly, 10 delta butterfly, 25 delta risk reversal and 10 delta risk reversal perfectly. If I ignore the 10 deltas in the calibration, then the 10 delta butterfly I get in the fitted model tends to be too large. How do people in practice deal with this? Are there modifications of SABR, that would not be too hard to implement, that allow better fits for 5 point smiles? I assume this would only be possible by adding parameters to the model. I have heard that banks tend to use modifications of SABR for pricing Vanilla options, so I would be curious what can be done here.

Comment: I do not think SABR is used that frequently in FX. If you want to stick to SABR,and trust the quotes you could use a different interpolation within the quoted spectrum, and SABR for extrapolation.